Performance of ArrayList<Integer> versus int[]
I have a million ints that I want to store in a data structure. I wanted to know whether the int array (int[]) is any more efficient than an ArrayList. Are there any performance gains to using int[] over ArrayList? I believe that ArrayList uses more memory than int[], but I don't know if that extra memory is negligible or not.
If I were to increase the size of the array (from one million to one billion ints) would the answer change? Is the extra memory used by ArrayList negligible or not?

ArrayLists only take objects so instead of 1M 32 bit ints stored in an array you would be storing 1M Integer Objects.  Of course, lists are easier to use and allow easier manipulation of values such as add, delete, remove, etc.  And they grow dynamically as needed.

@WJS True... ArrayList would store 1 million Integer objects. But an Integer object should be efficient and not take up that much memory. How big would the overhead be? Would the extra memory be negligible or non-negligible?

I would recommend you write the code first and then assess performance when it's done.  Start with a List.

Here is an ArrayList API. It has a brief note near the beginning about performance. But, remove requires the Objects following the one removed be shifted. Note it has an ensureCapacity method.

int[] uses the minimal space, whereas a List of Integer objects stores references to Integer objects, which each contain an int field.

There are also 3rd-party libraries to consider; e.g. Guava's Ints.asList(int[]) which wraps an int[] as a fixed-length List<Integer>

You also may want to consider IntBuffer, which has the performance benefits of an array, but gives you some but not all of the capabilities of a List.

look here, for perfomance information.

Project Valhalla / Value Objects should eliminate most/all of the differences if/when it emerges.

By default, the capacity of an ArrayList may be up to twice the number of elements it contains. So, if you know your expected size, specify an initial capacity. If the size is not known, trim when finished adding elements.
However, the main difference between ArrayList<Integer> and int[] is the difference between Integer and int: The former is an object, and each object stores some metadata for the JVM (runtime type, identity hash code, ...) in addition to its fields, which makes it somewhat bigger than a plain int. The size of this metadata is not specificed and may vary. You can measure it as follows:
public class Test {
    
    static final int elements = 10_000_000;
    
    private static long usedMemory() {
        var r = Runtime.getRuntime();
        return r.totalMemory() - r.freeMemory();
    }
    
    static void measure(String name, Runnable code) {
        System.gc(); // clean up previous tests
        long start = usedMemory();
        code.run();
        long end = usedMemory();
        System.out.println(name + " ".repeat(35 - name.length()) + " used " + (double)(end - start) / elements + " bytes/element");
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        measure("int[]", () -> { 
            var a = new int[elements];
        });
        measure("Integer[] with small numbers", () -> {
            var a = new Integer[elements];
            for (int i = 0; i < elements; i++) {
                a[i] = i % 64;
            }
        });
        measure("Integer[] with large numbers", () -> {
            var a = new Integer[elements];
            for (int i = 0; i < elements; i++) {
                a[i] = i;
            }
        });
        measure("ideal capacity ArrayList<Integer>", () -> {
            var a = new ArrayList<Integer>(elements);
            for (int i = 0; i < elements; i++) {
                a.add(i);
            }           
        });
        measure("auto sized ArrayList<Integer>", () -> {
            var a = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for (int i = 0; i < elements; i++) {
                a.add(i);
            }
        });
    }
}

On my JVM, this prints:
int[]                               used 4.1809328 bytes/element
Integer[] with small numbers        used 4.1949816 bytes/element
Integer[] with large numbers        used 20.7624576 bytes/element
ideal capacity ArrayList<Integer>   used 20.8476584 bytes/element
auto sized ArrayList<Integer>       used 30.3283208 bytes/element

That is, on this JVM, an Integer object takes up 16 bytes, and a refence to an object 4 bytes (if my heap were large enough, it would need 8 bytes instead). If the Integer contain small numbers, the Integer objects will be reused, and you only pay for the reference. In contrast, if the Integer objects contain large numbers, a new Integer is created for every element.
An ArrayList with ideal capacity is as big as an array of references. An ArrayList with automatic growth may be up to twice as large as needed.

The performance comparison will also depend on 1) whether the Integer values are created using Integer.valueOf(...) or autoboxing vs new Integer(...) 2) whether the numbers are typically small (and hence cached) or not, and 3) whether your JVM is using 32 bit or 64 bit references.  Your benchmark is pessimal with regards to 2.

However ... in all cases a int[] will use less space than an ArrayList with the same number of elements even if the latter has been trimmed using trimToSize.

@StephenC: Good point, I have now added a separate test case for that.

Beware: System.gc(); is a request, not an order. Garbage collection (GR) may or may not happen. The GC, if it does begin, may not complete before your code continues depending on the GC implementation. We have no control.
